# how to merge two lists in tcl8.4.x

Tags: tcl

I have lists like below as an output of some function,

```
puts $m 
{{bi 1/7 1/8}} {{uni 1/6}}
```

I need the above to be merged as `{{bi 1/7 1/8} {uni 1/6}}` as single list. I cant use `concat` as mine is 8.4.x. please help

Comment: You are aware that 8.4 is not supported?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure how deep you want the list concatenation to go (note that `concat` actually predates Tcl ***7.0*** so you certainly have it!) but here's how to strip one level of list-ness off, using code written to work with 8.4:

```
proc concat_one_level {input_list} {
    set accum_list {}
    foreach item $input_list {
        eval [linsert $item 0 lappend accum_list]
        # From 8.5 onwards, we'd use this instead:
        #    lappend accum_list {*}$item
    }
    return $accum_list
}
```

Testing it interactively (in 8.5; I don't have an 8.4 installation any more):

```
% puts $m 
{{bi 1/7 1/8}} {{uni 1/6}}
% concat_one_level $m
{bi 1/7 1/8} {uni 1/6}
% concat_one_level [concat_one_level $m]
bi 1/7 1/8 uni 1/6
```

Comment: Thanks Donal..Awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can install [tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/index.md), the `struct::list` package claims to still support such an ancient version of tcl, and has a [`flatten`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/struct/struct_list.md#10) command that will return your desired list.

Example `tclsh` repl session:

```
% package require struct::list
1.8.3
% set m {{{bi 1/7 1/8}} {{uni 1/6}}}
{{bi 1/7 1/8}} {{uni 1/6}}
% ::struct::list flatten $m
{bi 1/7 1/8} {uni 1/6}
% ::struct::list flatten -full $m
bi 1/7 1/8 uni 1/6
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the following may meet your needs:

```
% puts $m
{{bi 1/7 1/8}} {{uni 1/6}}
% puts [list [join $m]]
{{bi 1/7 1/8} {uni 1/6}}
% puts [llength [list [join $m]]]
1
%
```

```
% puts $m
{{bi 1/7 1/8}} {{uni 1/6}}
% puts [join $m]
{bi 1/7 1/8} {uni 1/6}
% puts [llength [join $m]]
2
%
```